# Creating a data-frame with Sequences of Dates

Tags: r, time, time-series

When creating a data-frame with Sequences of Dates (months from Jan. to Oct. 2018), with a list of values, I have following lines:

```
sales <- c(429, 400, 986, 618, 754, 424, 289, 401, 916, 852)
periods <- seq(as.Date("2018/1/1"), as.Date("2018/10/1"), "months")

Passengers <- data.frame(sales, periods)
pax <- ts(Passengers)

ggplot(pax, aes(x = months, y = sales)) + geom_line(colour = "grey75")
```

The output doesn't show a column of periods:

```
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 10 
Frequency = 1 
   sales periods
 1   429   17532
 2   400   17563
 3   986   17591
 4   618   17622
 5   754   17652
 6   424   17683
 7   289   17713
 8   401   17744
 9   916   17775
10   852   17805
```

The x axis of month doesn't show like a month, how can I have it displayed in yyyy-mm format? Thank you.

Comment: The periods column shows the numeric value of date objects spaced at intervals of months. I cannot tell what needs to be "corrected".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also confused as to what you expected as output. In `ts` you need to specify the time of the first observation and the number of observations per unit of time (see `?ts` for details and examples).

Perhaps you're after the functionality that `zoo` provides?

```
library(zoo)
z <- zoo(Passengers$sales, Passengers$periods)
plot(z)
```

[image]

```
time(z)
#[1] "2018-01-01" "2018-02-01" "2018-03-01" "2018-04-01" "2018-05-01"
#[6] "2018-06-01" "2018-07-01" "2018-08-01" "2018-09-01" "2018-10-01"
```